# AR core problem in movement of the object while animating

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, arcore

So I have been working on a project where I am making an zoo tycoon like game in AR.

I have imported few assets from unity asset store (A tiger for now).Now I wanted the Tiger to move around when clicked first I coded a very basic translation code for straight line movement only.It was successful than I watched a tutorial on movement + animation but when I add animation to it the tiger does not move when placed in AR world and only first animation plays

I have tried attaching this code to main script then tiger object itself also changing animation parameters such as pose, root motion etc but nothing works in the main scene the tiger is stuck playing the ideal animation.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class just : MonoBehaviour
{
    Animator anim;
    public float timer; //feeding timer value from inspector
    private bool isWalking = false;
    private float speedTiger = 0.2f;
    private float rotSpeed = 75.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = this.gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (!isWalking) //if tiger is not walking than playing the walking animition
        {
            anim.SetBool("walk", true);
            isWalking = true;
        }
        //translation in the forward direction
        this.gameObject.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speedTiger * Time.deltaTime);

        if (timer < 0) //when timer == 0 than stop the motion
        {
            speedTiger = 0;
            anim.SetBool("walk", false); //setting animaiton to idle animaiton
        }

        timer -= 1/50;

        //this.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speedTiger * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

The tiger should move with walk animation playing!

Comment: not the solution but instead of `timer -= 1/50` you really should use `timer -= Time.deltaTime;` (see [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html))

Comment: Ok i'll try it!